# In GWT: how to bookmark a page and be able to be redirected to it after authentication?

Tags: spring, gwt, authentication, redirect, oauth

I have implemented an OAuth2 authentication mechanism in my GWT app. The OAuth2 server is based on Spring framework 3.x (using its Spring security OAuth2 implementation).

I am using the OAuth2 *"Authorization code flow"* to get the user authenticated (though implicit flow may have been a better choice in our case). So at first, the user is redirected to the OAuth2 server authentication page, he enters his credentials and if he is successfully authenticated, he is redirected back to a url with an oauth code. He will then make a second call to get an access token from the OAuth2 server.

Now, the issue is, we would like the user **to be able to bookmark a page** in the application and **directly access it**. If he has already authenticated then he would have direct access to it (no more auth involved). Otherwise, he would have to go into the OAuth2 authentication flow but in the end, should be redirected back to the bookmarked page he intended to access at the beginning.

How can I *store this page* url and get redirected to it after the user successfully authenticates ?

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDITED**

The initial url redirection is done via javascript's *document.location.href*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to maintain the *original URI* in an OAuth 2.0 *Authorization Grant* flow is to pass it in the `state` parameter so that the *redirection endpoint* can use it, after it exchange the *authorization code* for an *access token,* to redirect the user back to that URI.

FYI, this is exactly what Google suggests in the examples in their OAuth 2.0 documentation, e.g. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

---

**Original answer:**

The problem is using the hash part of the URL for the *place*, which is not sent to the server  and thus cannot be used in the redirection to the OAuth2 server authentication page.

You have 2 (maybe 3) solutions:

- stop using the hash for the *place* and switch to HTML5 History; either through [`gwt-pushstate`](https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-pushstate) at the `History` level, or a [custom `PlaceHistoryHandler.Historian`](https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/1883821) if you use the Places API. That limits your audience though: http://caniuse.com/history
- stop using an HTTP redirect, and instead use JavaScript so you can put the hash in the OAuth2 `redirect_uri`. So instead of redirecting, send an *error page* with the appropriate scripts bits.
- some browsers append the hash to the URL after a redirection, so your OAuth2 server might be able to pick it (in JavaScript) and append it to the `redirect_uri`. That might depend on the HTTP status code used for redirecting (from experience, it works with a 301, but you don't want a 301 here). Needs testing.

Comment: Actually all the logic of *bookmarking* a page can be considered solved since I am using Activities and Places. But the real issue is how to intercept (using the EventBus perhaps?) the url of the first incoming request (which will fail obviously in case the user is not auth'ed yet), store it on the client side and redirecting the user to it after the access token is received (after auth is successful)

Comment: Is the redirect client side or server side?

Comment: It should be client side I think since I was thinking about firing an event when the OAuth2 flow ends, to trigger the redirect of the stored url. I mean the user is supposed to bookmark GWT-tokenized url (like this one : http://www.example.com/com.example.gwt.HistoryExample/HistoryExample.html#page1) so I guess it should be client side.

Comment: Whether is _should_ be client or server side is part of the solution, not the problem. Is it **currently** client-side or server-side? If it's client-side (which I'm doubtful about), then apply solution #2 using `Window.Location.getHref()`.

Comment: I am having a redirection on the client side : I have an index.html which has some Javascript code redirecting the user to the login page of the Authorization Server. After the authentication is successful, the user browser is redirected back to the *redirect_uri (OAuth)* which in my case, is a jsp page called *auth.jsp* - An OAuth2 auth-code is also provided in the url. This auth.jsp page then manages the retrieval of the access token from the authorization server using the authorization code. When I have the token back from the server, I just redirect the user to the main page of the app.

Comment: My bad, if you are talking about the OAuth redirect then it's *server side actually* : the redirect from the Authorization server is to my app's server side (auth.jsp for receiving the auth code and access token). You were right, I was wrong :)

Comment: I'm talking about the initial redirect, from your app to the auth server, because you're asking about the _initial URL_. If that redirect is done in JS, then it should be no problem including the place in the OAuth `redirect_uri`; but maybe you're not using a `redirect_uri` and use a fixed URI configured on your auth server?

Comment: Oh, so the *initial redirect* from the app to the Auth server is done via a plain **window.location.href**. Index.html is the only entrypoint into the app. Now, if the user *types in some random URL* directly in the browser address bar, then I have to be able to **save/store** this url in order to be able to redirect him back to it after authentication is okay. Now  you pointed out the `redirect_uri` as a way to handle it:if I use it then does it mean that any *potential redirect_uri* should be able to handle access token retrieval ? because that's what I thought the redirect_uri should do.

Comment: The `redirect_uri` is not fixed, I am providing it from the initial redirect request (via an HTTP GET parameter - redirect_uri). So yes I may be able to change it, but the issue is that as I have stated above, I thought the `redirect_uri` is only for managing token retrieval and since the user may potentially target many different urls, that would mean, all these urls would have to be able to do that. Or maybe it would be something I would have to include in every page which may be targeted. (My explanations may seem a little bit fuzzy sorry about that)

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. You'd pass your place (or _original URL_) in the `state`, and your redirection endpoint would use that `state` to redirect you to the appropriate URL. See examples in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Comment: awww jesus! thanks man : that really makes sense :) I have always underestimated the use of this state parameter. I am using it but only as a way to authenticate the request/response flow between the server and the app. I will explore your solution : I really think that should to the trick! Merci ;)... fortunately, I can not mark your comment as the solution :'( so I upvoted it. Maybe we'll edit the original post right after and point out that you provided the solution.

Comment: Edited the answer to point at the solution. I think you should provide the missing details (redirection done in JS on the client-side) in your question too.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using GWT [activities and places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).